# Какой будет результат компиляции и выполнения кода?

Tags: java

Решил освежить теоретические знания и возникли проблемы с понимаем принципов переопределения методов. Почему в данном случае вызывается метод родительского класса? Переопределение ведь должно сработать ведь модификатор доступа расширяется?

[image: Скриншот вопроса в тесте]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Переопределять методы с расширением уровня доступа возможно, но только не в случае переопределения метода с модификатором private, потому что в таком случае метод неявно помечается как final. Если вместо private подставить protected или default, то вызываться будет переопределенный метод класса Child.

Answer (score 5):

Тут задачка по всей видимости на внимательность.

У вас в Parent-е есть метод whoAreYou, он приватный. Соответственно раз вы объявили переменную p как Parent у вас и вызывается родительский метод. Если его сделать публичным, то ваш ответ будет верным.

Comment: Parent - это ведь ссылка на Child, который переопределяет метод whoAreYou() - переопределение ведь должно происходить, потому что модификатор доступа расширяется. Так почему все таки родительский вызывается?

Comment: Parent это Parent. Он не знает ничего о методах Child-a. Если вы в Child-e переопределите метод Parent-a тогда вызовется метод Child-a. Но в Child-e метод whoAreYou не переопределен т.к. в Parent-e он приватный и недоступен для Child-a. Если вы попробуете поставить аннотацию @Override в Child-e, то компилятор вам об этом скажет

Comment: @gianlucavachhi Из-за `private` этот метод в наследнике вообще *не виден*.

Answer (score 0):

```
Модификаторы доступа в родительском классе является private, это в свою очередь говорит о том, что этот метод может использоваться ТОЛЬКО внутри этого класса.
Соответственно не может быть @Override (переопределен) в дочернем классе, т.к тот не имеет доступа к нему.
Попробуйту написать над каждым из методов @Override и среда подсветит ошибкой.
```

Comment: Java ведь позволяет переопределять методы с расширением модификатора доступа, так почему же здесь переопределение не работает?

Comment: это похоже на такой пример: double a = 1; int b = a; (принудительно в этом случае мы конечно можем сделать кастинг, но сейчас не об этом) получается большее к меньшему нельзя приводить. int < double (по диапозону); private < public (по scope/область видимости)